# How to use Micrometer to measure the duration of an async method called from a controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, prometheus, spring-micrometer

I have to measure the full time of the request, that comes into controller and then the async method is executed  of some service:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;


    @GetMapping("/async")
    @Timed(value = "async.method.time", description = "Time taken to execute async method")
    public void async() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        someService.executeAsync();
    }
}

@Service
public class SomeService {

    @Async
    public void executeAsync() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("Async execution done!");
    }
}
```

Actually, if I put the `@Timed` annotation above the async service method, then it will be measured correct, but I would like to measure the time with controller method too. How can I achieve this using Micrometer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@NewSpan` annotation. This way will have the full controller execution time as well as break down of the @Async service execution time.

**NOTE:**

With Spring Boot 3.1.0 and Micrometer 1.10.0+, you can follow this [blog](https://medium.com/@amithkumarg/micrometer-tracing-in-spring-boot-context-propagation-for-async-scheduled-newspan-b80f4f4b2c9f) which guides you with the minimum setup required to enable Micrometer annotations with Spring Boot.

These [Medium](https://medium.com/) blog(s) are behind a paywall. If you are not already a member, no need to (pay) signup, you can directly find the source code here.

https://github.com/amithkumarg/springboot-otel-micrometer-jaeger

Comment: could you give an example pls?

Comment: @GeorgiiLvov - I have added the link to the github source code since the medium blog is behind a paywall for medium non-members.